# Dataframe transpose with pyspark in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, transpose

I have a dataframe `df` that have following structure:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|  s  |col_1|col_2|col_...|
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| f1  |  0.0|  0.6|  ...  |
| f2  |  0.6|  0.7|  ...  |
| f3  |  0.5|  0.9|  ...  |
|  ...|  ...|  ...|  ...  |
```

And I want to calculate the transpose of this dataframe so it will be look like

```
+-------+-----+-----+-------+------+
|  s    | f1  | f2  | f3    |   ...|
+-------+-----+-----+-------+------+
|col_1  |  0.0|  0.6|  0.5  |   ...|
|col_2  |  0.6|  0.7|  0.9  |   ...|
|col_...|  ...|  ...|  ...  |   ...|
```

I tied this two solutions but it returns that dataframe has not the specified used method:

method 1:

```
 for x in df.columns:
    df = df.pivot(x)
```

method 2:

```
df = sc.parallelize([ (k,) + tuple(v[0:]) for k,v in df.items()]).toDF()
```

how can I fix this.

Comment: You could take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215755/transpose-dataframe-using-spark-scala-without-using-pivot-function

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If data is small enough to be transposed (not pivoted with aggregation) you can just convert it to Pandas `DataFrame`:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("f1", 0.0, 0.6, 0.5),
    ("f2", 0.6, 0.7, 0.9)]).toDF(["s", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3"])

df.toPandas().set_index("s").transpose()
s       f1   f2
col_1  0.0  0.6
col_2  0.6  0.7
col_3  0.5  0.9
```

If it is to large for this, Spark won't help. Spark `DataFrame` distributes data by row (although locally uses columnar storage), therefore size of a individual rows is limited to local memory.

Comment: You might want to reset index before converting it back to Spark Dataframe in order to not lose columns names in the rows. You can do it by using the command 'reset_index'. E.g: df.toPandas().set_index("s").transpose().reset_index()

Comment: How can we convert the result to dataframe again ?

Comment: @Aspirant `spark.createDataFrame(result)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try Koalas by databricks. Koalas is a similar to Pandas but made for distributed processing and available in Pyspark (atleast from 3.0.0).

```
kdf = df.to_koalas()
kdf_t = kdf.transpose()
df_T = kdf_t.to_spark()
```

edit: to efficiently access Koalas you need to define partitions, otherwise there can be serious performance degradation.