# How to pivot on arbitrary column?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Apache Spark 2.2.0 and Scala.

I'm following [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36215755/1305344) as a guide to pivot a dataframe without using the pivot function.

I need to pivot the dataframe without using the pivot function as I have non-numerical data and `pivot` works with an aggregation function like `sum`, `min`, `max` on numerical data only. I've got a non-numerical column I'd like to use in `pivot` aggregation.

Here's my data:

```
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------+
|Qid|     Question|AnswerText|ParticipantID|Assessment| GeoTag|
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------+
|  1|Question1Text|       Yes|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)|
|  2|Question2Text|        No|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)|
|  3|Question3Text|         3|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)|
|  1|Question1Text|        No|       abcde2|         0|(x2,y2)|
|  2|Question2Text|       Yes|       abcde2|         0|(x2,y2)|
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------+
```

I want it to group by `ParticipantID`, `Assessment` and `GeoTag` tags and "pivot" on `Question` column and take the values from `AnswerText` column. In the end, the output should look as follows:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----+----- +
|ParticipantID|Assessment |GeoTag    |Qid_1  |Qid_2|Qid_3 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----+------+
|abcde1       |0          |(x1,y1)   |Yes    |No   |3     |
|abcde2       |0          |(x2,y2)   |No     |Yes  |null  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----+------+
```

I have tried this:

```
val questions: Array[String] = df.select("Q_id")
      .distinct()
      .collect()
      .map(_.getAs[String]("Q_id"))
      .sortWith(_<_)

val df2: DataFrame = questions.foldLeft(df) {
      case (data, question) => data.selectExpr("*", s"IF(Q_id = '$question', AnswerText, 0) AS $question")
    }
```

[followed by a GroupBy expression]

But I'm getting the following error, which must be something to do with the syntax of the final statement `AS $question`

```
17/12/08 16:13:12 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: *
17/12/08 16:13:12 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: IF(Q_id_string_new_2 = '101_Who_is_with_you_right_now?', AnswerText, 0) AS 101_Who_is_with_you_right_now?


extraneous input '?' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 104)

== SQL ==
IF(Q_id_string_new_2 = '101_Who_is_with_you_right_now?', AnswerText, 0) AS 101_Who_is_with_you_right_now?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input '?' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 104)

== SQL ==
IF(Q_id_string_new_2 = '101_Who_is_with_you_right_now?', AnswerText, 0) AS 101_Who_is_with_you_right_now?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Is there a better way? I thought about reverting to Pandas and Python outside Spark if necessary, but I'd rather write all the code within the same framework if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `$question` is substituting the value of the question variable into the SQL statement, you end up with a column name with '?' in it in SQL. `?` is not a valid character in a column name so you have to at least use backticks to quote:

```
s"IF(Q_id = '$question', AnswerText, 0) AS `$question`"
```

or use `select` / `withColumn`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

case (data, question) => 
  data.withColumn(question, when($"Q_id" === question, $"AnswerText"))
```

or santize strings first, using `regexp_replace`.

> need to pivot the dataframe without using the pivot function as I have non-numerical data and df.pivot only works with an aggregation function like sum, min, max on numerical data.

You can use `first`: [How to use pivot and calculate average on a non-numeric column (facing AnalysisException "is not a numeric column")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37486910/8371915)

```
data.groupBy($"ParticipantID", $"Assessment", $"GeoTag")
  .pivot($"Question", questions).agg(first($"AnswerText"))
```

Comment: Also please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643737/spark-applying-udf-to-dataframe-generating-new-columns-based-on-values-in-df

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to the [accepted answer by @user8371915](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47720937/1305344) to make the query a bit faster.

---

There is a way to avoid the expensive scan to generate `questions` with the headers.

Simply generate the headers (in the same job and stage!) followed by `pivot` on the column.

```
// It's a simple and cheap map-like transformation
val qid_header = input.withColumn("header", concat(lit("Qid_"), $"Qid"))
scala> qid_header.show
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------+------+
|Qid|     Question|AnswerText|ParticipantID|Assessment| GeoTag|header|
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------+------+
|  1|Question1Text|       Yes|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)| Qid_1|
|  2|Question2Text|        No|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)| Qid_2|
|  3|Question3Text|         3|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)| Qid_3|
|  1|Question1Text|        No|       abcde2|         0|(x2,y2)| Qid_1|
|  2|Question2Text|       Yes|       abcde2|         0|(x2,y2)| Qid_2|
+---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+-------+------+
```

With the headers as part of the dataset, let's pivot.

```
val solution = qid_header
  .groupBy('ParticipantID, 'Assessment, 'GeoTag)
  .pivot('header)
  .agg(first('AnswerText))
scala> solution.show
+-------------+----------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|ParticipantID|Assessment| GeoTag|Qid_1|Qid_2|Qid_3|
+-------------+----------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|       abcde1|         0|(x1,y1)|  Yes|   No|    3|
|       abcde2|         0|(x2,y2)|   No|  Yes| null|
+-------------+----------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: You don't avoid anything here Jacek, only hide. If `values` are not present  scan [will be performed internally](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala#L381-L387),  possibly [missing some values](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.scala#L378-L380)

Comment: I referred to generating the header (column) which is just a simple map-like transformation while in the OP's solution it was a separate job. For the columns themselves in `pivot` you're right, I do not avoid anything and did not even try to do so.

Comment: Hmmm.... The only job outside pivot in the OP is the one to generate `val questions: Array[String] = ...`, right? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Correct. A single job for `questions`. That's what I was referring to and that's why I started how to make your answer even better (and faster), but avoiding that one single job.

Comment: Then once again you don't save anything. Please check my first comment - if `values` are not provided, less precise equivalent of `questions` is computed by `pivot`. There will "additional" job, one way or another.

Comment: That's correct. With `pivot` you'll have the extra job to compute values for the columns. I don't get why they're less precise. Can you write a short app to demo what I could be missing? I'd appreciate.

Comment: Just consider what will happen if the number of unique values is larger than `spark.sql.pivotMaxValues + 1`  (by default 10 000 so it is rather border case) - `spark.range(15000, 1 to 15000).groupBy().pivot("id")`. Maybe precise is not the most fortunate choice of word.... Anyways, my main point is that your answer is technically correct, but the claim that is automagically _better (and faster)_ is not - `pivotMaxValues` notwithstanding both should do the same amount of work (sort in a single executor and sort after collect should make much difference). You don't want to spread FUD, do you? :)